# Centos 6.7 on VirtualBox loses network with SELinux disabled

Tags: networking, virtualbox, selinux

I've been struggling with this issue the whole day yesterday and it seems I'm in a dead end, too much Googling, reading, and trial and error without a result, so I decided to ask the gurus (you)

I'm gonna deploy (among other things) a CentOS 6.7 in 7 physical servers (which I don't yet the brand/model) with some packages, so.. in order to speed up things, I was making the whole procedure inside a Virtual Machine for avoiding any surprise later (I have only a pair of days)

The intallation procedures goes fine and I get into the system. I configure the network with static IP addreses, gateway and DNS, and everything goes fine.

I also have to disable SELinux and iptables service (client wants it disabled for their own reasons) and turn the max number of open files to 20000.

Here comes the problem. After rebooting, my eth0 is active and configured, BUT I cannot reach the gateway or any other IP.

A simple service network restart or ifdown/ifup eth0 solves this issue. BUT, again.. after rebooting.. same thing happens.

I've noticed that this does NOT happens if I let SELinux enabled (enforcing), in this case, I can reboot the machine and get to any IP without restarting the network service or the interface. Enabling/disabling iptables has no effect in this.

And this is where I still lost.

I'd also like to point out that before restarting the network service, if I execute a **route** command, it displays all the routes but the default gateway route with takes around 10 seconds to appear.

I'm Using:

-VirtualBox 5.0.2r102096 with bridged networking mode. I've tried WiFi and wired connection in the Host machine.
-CentOS 6.7 minimall install.

**/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0**

```
DEVICE=eth0
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=7db47baa-d1d4-43b9-9ef6-f4f1ce42e30d
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
HWADDR=08:00:27:F0:AE:9F
IPADDR=192.168.1.10
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERROUTES=no
PEERDNS=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=yes
IPV6INIT=no
NAME="System eth0"
```

**/etc/sysconfig/network**

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=master01
GATEWAY=192.168.1.1
DNS=192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

**chkconfig**
[image]

**ifconfig**
[image]

**route -n**
[image]

**route (before restarting network service)**
[image]

**route (after restarting network service)**
[image]

What else should I look?
Many, MANY thanks in advance for taking the time to read this question!!!!

Comment: What is `Livebox`? Can you show the output from `route -n` or `ip r` to skip the DNS resolution? Then you can look for whatever that IP address is under `/etc/sysconfig/network*` ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
LiveBox is the router. I'm editing the OP for adding the output of **route -n**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It turned out to be a VirtualBox issue, apparently, with the driver for the Intel E1000 adapter, disabling SeLinux gave me this problem. Using PCnet-FAST III adapter with the same previous configurations (and other too) worked perfect! rebooted all times I wanted and I had the network working, whether or not SELinux is disabled.
Thanks to the people that replied!